# How to auto-transcribe all MS Teams calls?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Microsoft Teams offers the possibility to *transcribe* a call. I would like to make this behavior the default, so that all meetings are transcribed by default, unless the host explicitly cancel the transcription.

Let's point out that I am not looking *captioning*, I am looking for the `.vtt` file produced at the end of the meeting when *transcribe* is activated. The point of this request to remove the need to think about clicking *transcribe* at the beginning of the meeting.

How can this behavior be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to Settings and toggle 'Captions' under 'Accessibility'.

[image]

You may also want to review these settings, while you're there.

[image]

Once you're in a call, you can adjust the transcribe settings for that call

[image]

When the call has finished, simply navigate to the `Recordings & Transcripts` tab in the chat, and you should see the meeting transcript.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up! It's very appreciated. Unfortunately, this does not produce the `.vtt` file that I am looking for. I have clarified the original question.

Comment: @JoannesVermorel updated the answer with how to find the transcript text.